# UnboundLocalError in pygame gradient function

Tags: python, scope

I was trying to make a rainbow gradient with this code, but I got an `UnboundLocalError`.

```python
import pygame, random, time

Red = 0
Blue = 0
Green = 0

background_color = (Red, Green, Blue)
(width, height) = (300, 200)


def ChangeRa():
   Red += 1
def ChangeGa():
   Green += 1
def ChangeBa():
   Blue += 1
def ChangeRs():
   Red += 1
def ChangeGs():
   Green += 1
def ChangeBs():
   Blue += 1

while Red <= 255:
   ChangeRa()
   time.sleep(0.1)
while Green <= 255:
   ChangeGa()
   time.sleep(0.1)
while Blue <= 255:
   ChangeBa()
   time.sleep(0.1)
while Red >= 0:
   ChangeRs()
   time.sleep(0.1)
while Green >= 0:
   ChangeGs()
   time.sleep(0.1)
while Blue >= 0:
   ChangeBs()
   time.sleep(0.1)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Rainbow!!!')
screen.fill(background_colour)

def close():
   running = True
   while running:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
   pygame.quit()

close()
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ronnochj/Fill.py", line 25, in <module>
    ChangeRa()
  File "/home/ronnochj/Fill.py", line 12, in ChangeRa
    Red += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Red' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing `Red` before assignment in here (same applies for `Blue` and `Green`):

```
def ChangeRa():
    Red += 1
```

You could say something like:

```
Red = 0
global Red
```

And then

```
def ChangeRa():
    Red += 1
```

Keep in mind that the outer `Red` is only defined outside of ChangeRa. Use global variables if you want them to be accessible within the functions.

*TLDR*:
Add `global Red, Blue, Green` on the line following `Green = 0`